# Como multiplicar quotes no R?

Tags: r

Esse pedaço de código está dentro de uma função que estou escrevendo. Nas últimas duas linhas está o meu problema.

```
firm1 = quote(q0_1 + c1 * q1 + c1_2 * q1) ## firm 1's cost curve
firm2 = quote(q0_2 + c2 * q2 + c2_2 * q2) ## firm 2's cost curve
q = quote(q1 + q2) #total supply

demand = quote(p_0 + a*q + b * q^2) # market demand curve

mg_cost1 = D(firm1, "q1") #firm 1's marginal cost/ supply curve
mg_cost2 = D(firm2, "q2") # firm 2's marginal cost/ supply curve

profit1 = (mg_cost1*demand) - firm1 #each firm's profit curve
profit2 = (mg_cost2*demand) - firm2
```

`mg_costi` e `demand` são quotes (útil para poder diferencia-las sem problemas), mas aparentemente multiplicar as quotes não é tão simples quanto multiplicar variáveis. Alguém sabe como fazer isso?

Comment: Para ficar mais claro, qual resultado você espera de `mg_cost1*demand`?

Comment: O resultado da multiplicação das funções, nada muito sofisticado. Um exemplo numérico explícito seria se mg_cost1 for f(x)=2x e demand for g(x) = 2+x então mg_cost1*demand = 4x + 2x².